# WebView Win8.1 app redirect

Tags: windows, webview, fiddler

I'm trying to diplay a webpage on a Win8.1 webview. This webpage authenticates the user with a SAP login process. If I run this on a browser, the redirect works succesfully. However, when I try to do it on the webview, it doesn't redirect to the application's main page. I tried using Fiddler to catch the requests being made by the webview, and the funny thing is that, when I have fiddler running, the webview works and it takes me to the main page. I thought it had something to do with the fact that it is calling another domain when it does the authentication. So I tried adding the list of Content URIs but the problem is that the web server is using http.

I also tried using an iFrame with a win8 app but I'm still not able to get to the main page.

Anybody had a similar issue?

Comment: What permissions does your app have? internetClient? privateNetworkClient? What are the URLs in question? Have you tried debugging your app?

Comment: internetClient I can't debug the app. I'm connecting to a server which is already built but I do not have access to the code

Comment: Uh, why can't you debug the app?